# Compare 2 objects ignoring null values

Tags: java, assertj

The project uses TestNg, Java11, Spring test

I am writing testNG tests for API
I have a java object that has this kind of stucture:

```
class Object1
    private Object2 o2;
    private List<Object3> o3;
```

Where `Object2` is not only composed of primitive attributes.

I would like to test if 2 `Object1` are equals with these rules:

- if actual `o2` is null, don't fail even if the other `o2` is not
- if actual `o3` is null or empty, don't fail even if the other `o3` is not
- if actual `o3` is not null nor empty, compare only non null `Object3` fields

To sum up, I would like to assert that 2 objects are the same, ignoring null fields recursively.

I could do it

```
assertThat(actual).usingRecursiveComparison().ignoringActualNullFields().isEqualTo(other);
```

but the recursive null fields are not ignored.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally created my own asserts like this:

```
import org.assertj.core.api.AbstractAssert;
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Object1Assert extends AbstractAssert<Object1Assert, Object1> {

    public Object1Assert isEqualTo(Object1 other) {

        // specially for null
        if(actual == other) {return this;}

        if(actual.getObject2() != null) {
            Assertions.assertThat(other.getObject2()).isEqualToIgnoringNullFields(actual.getObject2());
        }

        if(actual.getObject3() != null) {
            for(Object3 object3 : actual.getObject3()) {
                my.package.Assertions.assertThat(object3).isIn(other.getObject3());
            }
        }
        // return the current assertion for method chaining
        return this;
    }

    public Object1Assert(Object1 actual) {
        super(actual, Object1Assert.class);
    }

    public static Object1Assert assertThat(Object1 actual) {
        return new Object1Assert(actual);
    }

}
```

```
public class Assertions {

    public static Object3Assert assertThat(Object3 actual) {
        return new Object3Assert(actual);
    }
}
```

```
public class Object3Assert extends AbstractAssert<Object3Assert, Object3> {

    public Object3Assert isIn(List<Object3> others) {
        List<String> otherStringIds = others.stream().map(Object3::getStringId).collect(Collectors.toList());
        Assertions.assertThat(otherStringIds).isNotEmpty();
        Assertions.assertThat(actual.getStringId()).isIn(otherStringIds);
        for (Object3 otherObject3 : others) {
            if(actual.getStringId().equalsIgnoreCase(otherObject3.getStringId())) {
                Assertions.assertThat(otherObject3).usingComparatorForType(Comparators.bigDecimalComparator, BigDecimal.class).isEqualToIgnoringNullFields(actual);
            }
        }
        // return the current assertion for method chaining
        return this;
    }

    public Object3Assert(Object3 actual) {
        super(actual, Object3Assert.class);
    }

    public static Object3Assert assertThat(Object3 actual) {
        return new Object3Assert(actual);
    }

}
```

I created this class for each type I needed with this tutorial 
https://www.baeldung.com/assertj-custom-assertion

Comment: In order to make this a really helpful for future readers, why not give a small code snippet with some dummy classes and your assert?

Comment: I edited the answer to add more code and the tutorial I followed

Answer (score 0):

You can also ignore [expected null fields.](https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-recursive-comparison-ignoring-all-expected-null-fields).

Can you also provide a simple test to reproduce the issue? 
Feel free to raise an issue in https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues

Answer (score 0):

For me following code worked:

```
public class SocialLink {
    private String platform;
    private String link;
}

SocialLink obj1 = new SocialLink("Facebook", null);
SocialLink obj2 = new SocialLink("Facebook", null);

assertThat(obj1).isEqualToIgnoringNullFields(obj2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used this for other object but here I have a list of custom pojo, I is not as easy of this